# Как вернуть значение из блока?

Tags: ios, swift, вконтакте

Пишу приложение, которое работает с ВК при помощи фреймворка SwiftyVK. Имеется следующий код:

```
var photoID = ""
VK.API.Upload.Photo.toWall.toUser(media, userId: userIDForVK).send(
    onSuccess: { response in
        print("!!!!!!!!!!! SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto success \n \(response)")
        photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue },
    onError: { error in
        print("!!!!!!!!!!! SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto fail \n \(error)") },
    onProgress: { done, total in
        print("!!!!!!!!!!! SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto progress: \(done) of \(total))") }
)
```

где блоки onSuccess, onError и onProgress имеют тип `(JSON) -> ()`. Мне нужно вытащить конкретное значение из переменной response блока onSuccess, как это сделать? Мой код не работает, переменная photoID как была, так и остается пустой.

**UPD:** Внесу больше ясности в свой вопрос:
У меня есть некоторая функция `sendToVK(message: String, photos: [UIImage])`. Опишу в общих чертах ее тело:

```
func sendToVK(message: String, photos: [UIImage]) {
    // описание некоторых переменных
    var attachments = "" // в этой переменной в итоге должна лежать информация обо всех фотографиях, 
//которые я хочу прикрепить к посту, в виде "photo123456_987654,photo123456_612366,photo123456_123156",
// где 123456 - это id юзера, к которому на стену загрузятся фотки (он у меня уже есть),
// а цифры после "_" - это как раз id непосредственно фотографии, 
//который приходит в ответе сервера после успешной загрузки фото

    for photo in photos {
       // в этом цикле загружаю на сервер фотографии, и по идее где то в нем же я должен получать ID фотографии из ответа (response) сервера для дальнейшей работы
      //в этом же цикле выполняется кусок кода, опубликованный в моем самом первом сообщении
      //пусть photoString - это сформированная строка вида "photo12345_612515"

      attachments += photoString
    }

    //тут в wallPostParameters есть все параметры, необходимые для публикации, включая и attachments
    VK.API.Wall.post(wallPostParameters).send(
            onSuccess: {response in print(response)},
            onError: {error in print(error)},
            onProgress: {done, total in print(" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! send \(done) of \(total)")}
        )
}
```

И сама проблема заключается в том, что в цикле, где я итерирую по фотографиям, задача загрузки на сервер отправляется на другой поток, соответственно, ответ в **photoString**  записывается тоже в другое время "где-то там". И по факту получается, что к моменту, когда мне уже нужны заполненные **attachments** (прямо перед вызовом VK.API.Wall.post), они заполнены *без ID фотографий*, то есть строкой вида "photo123456_,photo123456_,photo123456_", потому что где-то в другом потоке эти фотографии еще не успели загрузиться, и, как следствие, в строку attachments необходимые ID не были добавлены.

Суть вопроса заключается в следующем: как мне реализовать на свифте то, что в цикле при каждой итерации мы не продолжаем выполнение, а ждем загрузки фото, добавляем ее id в **photoString** и накапливаем эти **photoString** в **attachments**, чтобы перед вызовом VK.API.Wall.post все было готово к отправке?

Comment: А как(и главное когда) вы проверяете, что она остаётся пустой?

Comment: @vp_arth сразу же после данного кода идет строка `let photoString = "photo" + userIDForVK + "_" + photoID` и после нее стоит breakpoint. Когда моя программа выполняется и останавливается на брейкпоинте, то я смотрю на значения переменных в данный момент и вижу, что photoID == "", а в photoString лежит значение вида "photo12345_", то есть photoID к ней никакой и не присоединился.

Comment: Но ведь и `print` в `onSuccess` ещё не выполнился, не так ли? У вас асинхронная операция с коллбеком, вы не можете получить значение синхронно.

Comment: Вот тут можете почитать про ту же проблему в javascript: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0

Comment: @vp_arth принт выполнился, он мне выводит даже информацию о содержимом response на консоль. И потом уже идет остановка на брейкпоинте. Конечно, это все равно не дает гарантии, что они выполняются синхронно (более того, я тоже почти уверен, что это асинхронная операция), но, тем не менее, я ведь выполняю строку `photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue` непосредственно в блоке асинхронного кода. И если мне выводит на консоль информацию, значит и присваивать должно сразу после этого. В общем, очень странно

Comment: @vp_arth добавил больше информации в вопрос

Comment: Я вам тут не помощник, я не знаю swift :) Просто подсказал наиболее очевидное направление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После прочтения статьи (https://habrahabr.ru/post/320152/) пришел к следующему решению:

```
private static func sendToVK(_ message: String, photos: [UIImage], userIDForVK: String) {
        var wallPostParameters = Dictionary<VK.Arg, String>()
        wallPostParameters[VK.Arg.message] = message
        var attachments = ""
        var successfulUploadsCount = 0

        let sendPostWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
            VK.API.Wall.post(wallPostParameters).send(
            onSuccess: {response in print(response)},
            onError: {error in print(error)},
            onProgress: {done, total in print("\n send \(done) of \(total)\n")} )
        }

        for photo in photos {
            let media = Media(imageData: Data(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 1.0)!), type: Media.ImageType.JPG)

            VK.API.Upload.Photo.toWall.toUser(media, userId: userIDForVK).send(

                onSuccess: { response in
                    let photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue
                    let photoString = "photo" + userIDForVK + "_" + photoID

                    if attachments.isEmpty {
                        attachments = photoString
                    } else {
                        attachments += "," + photoString
                    }
                    successfulUploadsCount += 1

                    if successfulUploadsCount == photos.count {
                        wallPostParameters[VK.Arg.attachments] = attachments
                        sendPostWorkItem.perform()
                    }
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto success \n \(response)\n") },

                onError: { error in
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto fail \n \(error)\n") },

                onProgress: { done, total in
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto progress: \(done) of \(total))\n") } )
        }

        if photos.isEmpty {
            sendPostWorkItem.perform()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение на скорую руку с использованием Swift 3.3 (не утверждаю что оно идеально, но если проект надо срочно завершить то сойдёт):

```
//Решить проблемы можно с помощью примитива сихронизации под названием семафор
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    print("Фотография загружена!!!")
    //Завершим ожидание загрузки
    semaphore.signal()
}
//Ждём 30 секунд пока выполнится блок (в Вашем случае пока загрузится фотография)
let timeout = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(30)
if semaphore.wait(timeout: timeout) == .timedOut {

    //Если даже через 30 секунд фотографии нет, оповестим об этом пользователей
    print("Извините, но мы не можем загрузить Вашу фотографию")
} else {

    //Здесь уже можете делать с вашей фотографией или её идентификатором что хотите
    print("Фотография готова")
}
```

Здесь для примера я работал с очередями, но думаю вам суть решения будет итак понятна.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я в итоге нашел большую и очень полезную статью про многопоточность на хабре, прочитал ее и сделал по-своему (см. мой ответ)